# Proof verification: Atiyah MacDonald 2.7

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

I'm looking for verification or assistance with a few details in the proof of exercise 2.7 in Atiyah & MacDonald. My proof is below, with some comments afterwards:

**Question:** Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $A$. Show that $\mathfrak{p}[x]$ is a prime ideal in $A[x]$. If $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal in $A$, is $\mathfrak{m}[x]$ a maximal ideal in $A[x]$?

**Solution:** Let $A$ be a ring, $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $A$, $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in $A$, and $I$ be any ideal of $A$. We first prove that $A[x] / IA[x] \cong (A / I)[x]$, using the tensor product. By a previous exercise (exercise 2.2) we have that for any ring $A$, ideal $I$, and $A$-module $M$, $(A / I) \otimes_A M \cong M / IM$. Thus we have that $(A / I) \otimes_A A[x] \cong A[x] / IA[x]$. By another exercise (exercise 2.6) we have that since $A / I$ is an $A$-module, $(A / I) \otimes_A A[x] \cong (A / I)[x]$. Thus $(A / I)[x] \cong A[x] / IA[x]$ as $A$-modules. We therefore have that $(A / \mathfrak{p})[x] \cong A[x] / \mathfrak{p}[x]$. Since $A / \mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain, so is $(A / \mathfrak{p})[x]$, and therefore $A[x] / \mathfrak{p}[x]$ is an integral domain, and $\mathfrak{p}[x]$ is a prime ideal. On the other hand, $\mathfrak{m}[x]$ might not be a maximal ideal, since $A[x] / \mathfrak{m}[x] \cong (A / \mathfrak{m})[x]$ might not be a field (consider, for example, the case that $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{m} = p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$).

**Notes:** My concern is that the previous exercises give isomorphisms *as $A$-modules*, whereas when we conclude that since $(A/\mathfrak{p})[x]$ is an integral domain, so is $A[x] / \mathfrak{p}[x]$, it seems that we need to have a *ring isomorphism*, so that products on the left correspond to products on the right. We could get the ring isomorphism by other means (it's Proposition 9.1.2 in my edition of Dummit & Foote), but the proof above seems to be more in the spirit of the section of Atiyah & MacDonald. Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that all of these are not just modules, but algebras over $A$. In this case the tensor product is also an $A$-algebra, so multiplication makes sense. So check if the maps you defined are closed under multiplication. (this indeed doesn't follow from the universal property, it has to be checked) Clearly, it is enough to check on simple tensors.